# How do I use a composite pk in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, mariadb, composite-primary-key

I'm new to stored procedure's and I want to create a stored procedure where I go through three tables to get to the data I need and the third table has a composite pk that makes me a bit crazy and I just can't look through this problem right know. But I have to solve it.

I have a db with three tables that are related to each other - `player`, `company`, `company_resource`. The tables `player` and `company` have normal pk's (`id`) where as `company_resource` have a composite pk (`company_id`, `resource_id` - `resource_id` is from another table that is irrelevant right know). Also the `company` table has a foreign key `player_id`

So it look's like this:

```
player-Table:

id
1
2
3
4
...
```

```
company-Table:

id     player_id (fk)
1      1
2      1
3      2
4      3
...
```

```
company_resource-Table:

company_id (pk)   resource_id (pk)
1                 1
1                 2
1                 3
1                 4
2                 1
2                 2
```

Know I want to pass a `player_id` to my stored procedure and first get all the companies with identical `player_id` and then get all the `company_resource` entries for the companies found from the given `player_id`.

My main goal is to get all resources from companies that belong to a specific player and then to sum a specific column, so I can write the result value of the summation to a column of the `player` table.

I already searched for different posts but couldn't find any fitting solution.

Comment: is this about mysql or about sql-server ? they are both very different databases

Comment: Actually it should be `mariaDB`. But I think `mysql` and `mariaDB` are in this case the same or? Hope its better now.

Comment: You simply need a join. No need for stored procedures here. And the pk is there to ensure data consistency. You don't even need to know about it when you select.

Comment: I just can't see through this problem. Could you give an example how such a join should look like?

Comment: There are several good SQL tutorials for free on line that can help you with the `JOIN` concept and syntax. In the database world, writing a `JOIN` is on a par with a "Hello World" exercise, and that's not really what Stack Overflow excels at. Once you've attempted your query, if it doesn't return the result you expect, take a look at [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/), then come back and either edit your question or start a new one and we'll help you work out any issues you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't write the stored procedure logic, but this is a simple join.

You connect the company table to the company resource table based on the shared key (company id); you then limit the number of companies you look at by specifying the player_id.

```
select *
from company c
inner join company_resource cr
  on c.company_id = cr.company_id
where c.player_id = ?
```